# How do I use TensorFlow to add Predicted Value to an empty column in a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow

So I have this great bit of code that comes out with approximately a 93% accuracy rate on its predictions. What I'm wondering how to do now is to take the trained program, make it look at actual test data without the answer on it, and make it fill in the answer regardless of the accuracy. Here's the code that I have that predicts with a ~93% accuracy rate.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt
import sklearn

# Convert to one hot
def convertOneHot(data):
    y=np.array([int(i[0]) for i in data])
    y_onehot=[0]*len(y)
    for i,j in enumerate(y):
        y_onehot[i]=[0]*(y.max() + 1)
        y_onehot[i][j]=1
    return (y,y_onehot)

data = genfromtxt('cs-training.csv',delimiter=',')  # Training data
test_data = genfromtxt('cs-test.csv',delimiter=',')  # Test data

x_train=np.array([ i[1::] for i in data])
y_train,y_train_onehot = convertOneHot(data)

x_test=np.array([ i[1::] for i in test_data])
y_test,y_test_onehot = convertOneHot(test_data)

A=data.shape[1]-1 # Number of features, Note first is y
B=len(y_train_onehot[0])
tf_in = tf.placeholder("float", [None, A]) # Features
tf_weight = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([A,B]))
tf_bias = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([B]))
tf_softmax = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(tf_in,tf_weight) + tf_bias)

# Training via backpropagation
tf_softmax_correct = tf.placeholder("float", [None,B])
tf_cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(tf_softmax_correct*tf.log(tf_softmax))

# Train using tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer
tf_train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(tf_cross_entropy)

# Add accuracy checking nodes
tf_correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(tf_softmax,1), tf.argmax(tf_softmax_correct,1))
tf_accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf_correct_prediction, "float"))

saver = tf.train.Saver([tf_weight,tf_bias])

# Initialize and run
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

print("...")
# Run the training
for i in range(100):
    sess.run(tf_train_step, feed_dict={tf_in: x_train, tf_softmax_correct: y_train_onehot})

#Print accuracy
    result = sess.run(tf_accuracy, feed_dict={tf_in: x_test, tf_softmax_correct: y_test_onehot})
print result
```

Now I have the actual test set `cs-test-actual.csv` where the first column is entirely empty and I need to fill it in with a predicted 1 or 0. How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 3):

The program above doesn't appear to be saving the trained session. I think you want to do this in two steps.

1. Train and save the session
2. Restore the save session, and run test data through it.

**Step 1:**

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python

 import tensorflow as tf
 import numpy as np
 from numpy import genfromtxt
 import sklearn

 # Convert to one hot
 def convertOneHot(data):
     y=np.array([int(i[0]) for i in data])
     y_onehot=[0]*len(y)
     for i,j in enumerate(y):
         y_onehot[i]=[0]*(y.max() + 1)
         y_onehot[i][j]=1
     return (y,y_onehot)

 # Build Example Data is CSV format, but use Iris data
 from sklearn import datasets
 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
 def buildDataFromIris():
     iris = datasets.load_iris()
     X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(iris.data, iris.target, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
     f=open('cs-training.csv','w')
     for i,j in enumerate(X_train):
         k=np.append(np.array(y_train[i]),j   )
         f.write(",".join([str(s) for s in k]) + '\n')
     f.close()
     f=open('cs-test.csv','w')
     for i,j in enumerate(X_test):
         k=np.append(np.array(y_test[i]),j   )
         f.write(",".join([str(s) for s in k]) + '\n')
     f.close()

 # Recreate logging and save dir
 # Seems the tensorflow won't always overwrite
 import shutil, os, sys
 TMPDir='./tensorTMP'
 try:
  shutil.rmtree(TMPDir)
 except:
  print "Tmp Dir did not exist...that's okay"
 os.mkdir(TMPDir, 0755 )



 # Populate the data
 buildDataFromIris()

 data = genfromtxt('cs-training.csv',delimiter=',')  # Training data
 test_data = genfromtxt('cs-test.csv',delimiter=',')  # Test data

 x_train=np.array([ i[1::] for i in data])
 y_train,y_train_onehot = convertOneHot(data)

 x_test=np.array([ i[1::] for i in test_data])
 y_test,y_test_onehot = convertOneHot(test_data)

 A=data.shape[1]-1 # Number of features, Note first is y
 B=len(y_train_onehot[0])
 tf_in = tf.placeholder("float", [None, A]) # Features
 tf_weight = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([A,B]))
 tf_bias = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([B]))
 tf_softmax = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(tf_in,tf_weight) + tf_bias)

 # Training via backpropagation
 tf_softmax_correct = tf.placeholder("float", [None,B])
 tf_cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(tf_softmax_correct*tf.log(tf_softmax))

 # Train using tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer
 tf_train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(tf_cross_entropy)

 # Add accuracy checking nodes
 tf_correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(tf_softmax,1), tf.argmax(tf_softmax_correct,1))
 tf_accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf_correct_prediction, "float"))

 saver = tf.train.Saver([tf_weight,tf_bias])

 # Initialize and run
 init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
 sess = tf.Session()
 sess.run(init)

 THRESHOLD = 0.98
 saved = False
 print("...")
 # Run the training
 for i in range(100):
     sess.run(tf_train_step, feed_dict={tf_in: x_train, tf_softmax_correct: y_train_onehot})
     result = sess.run(tf_accuracy, feed_dict={tf_in: x_test, tf_softmax_correct: y_test_onehot})
     # If it's well trained on this iteration, save it. We just need one save.
     if result > THRESHOLD  and saved == False:
         saved = True
         print "saving result {}".format(result)
         saver.save(sess,TMPDir +"/savedSess")
```

The only modifications made were generating sample data using Iris, establishing a THRESHOLD or confidence interval for the session. If it's over that THRESHOLD, then, save the session.  After running step one, the model should be trained and saved.

**Step 2:**

Restore the saved session, and run the training data through it.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python

 import tensorflow as tf
 import numpy as np
 from numpy import genfromtxt
 import sklearn

 # Convert to one hot
 def convertOneHot(data):
     y=np.array([int(i[0]) for i in data])
     y_onehot=[0]*len(y)
     for i,j in enumerate(y):
         y_onehot[i]=[0]*(y.max() + 1)
         y_onehot[i][j]=1
     return (y,y_onehot)


 data = genfromtxt('cs-training.csv',delimiter=',')  # Training data
 test_data = genfromtxt('cs-test.csv',delimiter=',')  # Test data

 x_train=np.array([ i[1::] for i in data])
 y_train,y_train_onehot = convertOneHot(data)

 x_test=np.array([ i[1::] for i in test_data])
 y_test,y_test_onehot = convertOneHot(test_data)

 A=data.shape[1]-1 # Number of features, Note first is y
 B=len(y_train_onehot[0])
 tf_in = tf.placeholder("float", [None, A]) # Features
 tf_weight = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([A,B]))
 tf_bias = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([B]))
 tf_softmax = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(tf_in,tf_weight) + tf_bias)

 # Training via backpropagation
 tf_softmax_correct = tf.placeholder("float", [None,B])
 tf_cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(tf_softmax_correct*tf.log(tf_softmax))

 # Train using tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer
 tf_train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(tf_cross_entropy)

 # Add accuracy checking nodes
 tf_correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(tf_softmax,1), tf.argmax(tf_softmax_correct,1))
 tf_accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf_correct_prediction, "float"))

 saver = tf.train.Saver([tf_weight,tf_bias])

 # Initialize and run
 init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
 sess = tf.Session()
 sess.run(init)

 TMPDir='./tensorTMP'
 saver.restore(sess, TMPDir + '/savedSess')
 ans = sess.run(tf_softmax, feed_dict={tf_in: x_test, tf_softmax_correct: y_test_onehot})

 print ans
```

Note, your output will look like the following...

```
[[  6.17585704e-02   8.63590300e-01   7.46511072e-02]
[  9.98804331e-01   1.19561062e-03   3.25832108e-13]
[  1.52018686e-07   4.49650863e-04   9.99550164e-01]
```

Comment: This works on the Iris data provided by sklearn but it doesn't work for my project. It returns nothing but `nan` for every place where there should be a 1, a 0, or even a probability (which I hope it returns more than anything).